# How to retrieve rows using SQL Lag() function with condition

Tags: sql, loops, apache-spark-sql, window-functions, lag

I've been trying to solve this problem but failing to get the desired results. Please help as I've been trying for days.

I have the table below where click_time and fetches_before_click column is the result I need.

1. Calculate the time difference in unix_time_seconds column between a "click" action and the "fetch" which is before the click and has flag = 2.
2. Calculate the number of rows between the "click" and the prior "fetch" with "flag = 2" meeting the above criteria. The column fetches_before_click shows how many "fetches" it took user before the "click" event

The click_time column shows the difference only between the "click" row and the first row before click which has flag = 2 and event=fetch

I used the following statement but I am not sure how to go backwards and find the first row which is "fetch" and has value = "2" and take that row and subtract from the click.
I used the lag() function to read previous rows but its getting stuck at getting to the previous row which has flag=2 and event = fetch

```
 select time, unix_time_seconds,event,flag,
 case when event = "click"
   then unix_time_seconds - lag(unix_time_seconds, 1 ) over (order by flag desc)
 end as click_time

 from table_event
```

| time | unix_time_seconds | event | flag | click_time | fetches_before_click |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/2/22 3:52 | 1641095536 | fetch | 2 |  |  |
| 1/2/22 3:52 | 1641095539 | click | 0 | 3 | 1 |
| 1/2/22 4:59 | 1641099553 | fetch | 2 |  |  |
| 1/2/22 4:59 | 1641099561 | fetch | 1 |  |  |
| 1/2/22 4:59 | 1641099568 | fetch | 1 |  |  |
| 1/2/22 4:59 | 1641099575 | fetch | 1 |  |  |
| 1/2/22 6:51 | 1641106302 | fetch | 2 |  |  |
| 1/2/22 6:51 | 1641106317 | fetch | 1 |  |  |
| 1/2/22 6:51 | 1641106319 | click | 0 | 17 | 2 |
| 1/3/22 6:15 | 1641190520 | fetch | 2 |  |  |
| 1/7/22 8:12 | 1641543135 | fetch | 2 |  |  |
| 1/10/22 1:09 | 1641776996 | fetch | 2 |  |  |
| 1/10/22 1:09 | 1641776997 | click | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1/10/22 1:12 | 1641777179 | fetch | 2 |  |  |
| 1/10/22 1:13 | 1641777181 | click | 0 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: *not sure how to go backwards* - you use a WHERE to throw away the uninteresting rows between, so that it's one row behind the click row

Comment: Spark is working only with ISO date & timestamp format, e.g. '2012-02-28 11:22:33' or '2012-02-28T11:22:33'. Fix your data sample.

Comment: Thanks David, I have converted the date/timestamp i.e. "time" column to a more user friendly format but in this case each date/timestamp is already converted to unix-timestamp-seconds so that it is easier to take difference between timestamps in seconds. The time column is only used for sorting.

Comment: That's even worse. If you'll sort by the `time` column it will be an alphabetic sort and you'll get the wrong results.

Comment: And another thing - the header of your post is "How to retrieve rows using SQL Lag() function with condition". It is a really bad practice to force a solution when you are asking for help.

Comment: Thanks David! I will try better ways next time and thanks for posting the solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to this question, here is one of them.

Note the use of [values](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-inline-table.html) for the creation of an ad hoc dataset.
Another way for doing that, is by using the [stack](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#stack) function
Also note the use of [timestamp literal](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-literals.html#datetime-literal), e.g. `timestamp '2022-01-02 03:52:16'`

The outer CASE statement is in order to display click_time values only for click events.

The window function is ordering the records by the unix_time_seconds and for each record takes the max unix_time_seconds up until this record (`order by` in this context is actually an implied syntax for `order by ... rows between unbounded preceding and current row`).
The CASE statement within the window function makse sure that we're looking only on fetch events with 2 flag.

```
with t (time, unix_time_seconds, event, flag)
as
(
  select   *
  from     values  (timestamp '2022-01-02 03:52:16', 1641095536, 'fetch', 2)
                  ,(timestamp '2022-01-02 03:52:19', 1641095539, 'click', 0)
                  ,(timestamp '2022-01-02 04:59:13', 1641099553, 'fetch', 2)
                  ,(timestamp '2022-01-02 04:59:21', 1641099561, 'fetch', 1)
                  ,(timestamp '2022-01-02 04:59:28', 1641099568, 'fetch', 1)
                  ,(timestamp '2022-01-02 04:59:35', 1641099575, 'fetch', 1)
                  ,(timestamp '2022-01-02 06:51:42', 1641106302, 'fetch', 2)
                  ,(timestamp '2022-01-02 06:51:57', 1641106317, 'fetch', 1)
                  ,(timestamp '2022-01-02 06:51:59', 1641106319, 'click', 0)
                  ,(timestamp '2022-01-03 06:15:20', 1641190520, 'fetch', 2)
                  ,(timestamp '2022-01-07 08:12:15', 1641543135, 'fetch', 2)
                  ,(timestamp '2022-01-10 01:09:56', 1641776996, 'fetch', 2)
                  ,(timestamp '2022-01-10 01:09:57', 1641776997, 'click', 0)
                  ,(timestamp '2022-01-10 01:12:59', 1641777179, 'fetch', 2)
                  ,(timestamp '2022-01-10 01:13:01', 1641777181, 'click', 0)
)
select    *
         ,case 
         
             when  event == 'click' 
             
             then  unix_time_seconds 
             
                 - max(case 
                           when event = 'fetch' and flag = 2 
                           then unix_time_seconds 
                       end
                       ) over (order by unix_time_seconds)
          end as click_time
          
from      t
```

| time | unix_time_seconds | event | flag | click_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-02T03:52:16.000+0000 | 1641095536 | fetch | 2 | null |
| 2022-01-02T03:52:19.000+0000 | 1641095539 | click | 0 | 3 |
| 2022-01-02T04:59:13.000+0000 | 1641099553 | fetch | 2 | null |
| 2022-01-02T04:59:21.000+0000 | 1641099561 | fetch | 1 | null |
| 2022-01-02T04:59:28.000+0000 | 1641099568 | fetch | 1 | null |
| 2022-01-02T04:59:35.000+0000 | 1641099575 | fetch | 1 | null |
| 2022-01-02T06:51:42.000+0000 | 1641106302 | fetch | 2 | null |
| 2022-01-02T06:51:57.000+0000 | 1641106317 | fetch | 1 | null |
| 2022-01-02T06:51:59.000+0000 | 1641106319 | click | 0 | 17 |
| 2022-01-03T06:15:20.000+0000 | 1641190520 | fetch | 2 | null |
| 2022-01-07T08:12:15.000+0000 | 1641543135 | fetch | 2 | null |
| 2022-01-10T01:09:56.000+0000 | 1641776996 | fetch | 2 | null |
| 2022-01-10T01:09:57.000+0000 | 1641776997 | click | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-01-10T01:12:59.000+0000 | 1641777179 | fetch | 2 | null |
| 2022-01-10T01:13:01.000+0000 | 1641777181 | click | 0 | 2 |

**This solution was tested on Azure Databricks, RT 10.1 with Apache Spark 3.2.0**

Comment: Thanks! is it also possible to calculate the number of rows between the click and the fetch we used to take the difference. This can help develop how many fetches it took for the user before click?

Comment: Thanks much David, this worked and I was also able to use this approach to solve for another dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding `partition by (case when event='click' or flag=2 then 1 end)` in your window function will server the purpose. This condition will ignore all the rows where the event is not 'click' or event is 'fetch' and flag is not 2.

Instead of all fifteen rows `lag()` window function will only consider below 11 rows.

| time | unix_time_seconds | event | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 03:52:16 | 1641095536 | fetch | 2 |
| 2022-02-01 03:52:19 | 1641095539 | click | 0 |
| 2022-02-01 04:59:13 | 1641099553 | fetch | 2 |
| 2022-02-01 06:51:42 | 1641106302 | fetch | 2 |
| 2022-02-01 06:51:59 | 1641106319 | click | 0 |
| 2022-03-01 06:15:20 | 1641190520 | fetch | 2 |
| 2022-07-01 08:12:15 | 1641543135 | fetch | 2 |
| 2022-10-01 01:09:56 | 1641776996 | fetch | 2 |
| 2022-10-01 01:09:57 | 1641776997 | click | 0 |
| 2022-10-01 01:12:59 | 1641777179 | fetch | 2 |
| 0122-10-01 01:13:01 | 1641777181 | click | 0 |

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table table_event(time datetime,    unix_time_seconds int,  event varchar(10), flag int);
 insert into table_event values('22/2/1 3:52:16',   1641095536, 'fetch',    2);
 insert into table_event values('22/2/1 3:52:19',   1641095539, 'click',    0);
 insert into table_event values('22/2/1 4:59:13',   1641099553, 'fetch',    2);
 insert into table_event values('22/2/1 4:59:21',   1641099561, 'fetch',    1);
 insert into table_event values('22/2/1 4:59:28',   1641099568, 'fetch',    1);     
 insert into table_event values('22/2/1 4:59:35',   1641099575, 'fetch',    1);
 insert into table_event values('22/2/1 6:51:42',   1641106302, 'fetch',    2);
 insert into table_event values('22/2/1 6:51:57',   1641106317, 'fetch',    1);
 insert into table_event values('22/2/1 6:51:59',   1641106319, 'click',    0);
 insert into table_event values('22/3/1 6:15:20',   1641190520, 'fetch',    2);
 insert into table_event values('22/7/1 8:12:15',   1641543135, 'fetch',    2); 
 insert into table_event values('22/10/1 1:09:56',  1641776996, 'fetch',    2); 
 insert into table_event values('22/10/1 1:09:57',  1641776997, 'click',    0);
 insert into table_event values('22/10/1 1:12:59',  1641777179, 'fetch',    2); 
 insert into table_event values('122/10/1 1:13:01', 1641777181, 'click',    0);
```

Query:

select time, unix_time_seconds,event,flag,
case when event = 'click'
then unix_time_seconds - lag(unix_time_seconds, 1 ) over (partition by (case when event='click' or(event='fetch' and flag=2) then 1 end) order by time  )
end as click_time

from table_event
order by unix_time_seconds

Output:

| time | unix_time_seconds | event | flag | click_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 03:52:16 | 1641095536 | fetch | 2 | *null* |
| 2022-02-01 03:52:19 | 1641095539 | click | 0 | 3 |
| 2022-02-01 04:59:13 | 1641099553 | fetch | 2 | *null* |
| 2022-02-01 04:59:21 | 1641099561 | fetch | 1 | *null* |
| 2022-02-01 04:59:28 | 1641099568 | fetch | 1 | *null* |
| 2022-02-01 04:59:35 | 1641099575 | fetch | 1 | *null* |
| 2022-02-01 06:51:42 | 1641106302 | fetch | 2 | *null* |
| 2022-02-01 06:51:57 | 1641106317 | fetch | 1 | *null* |
| 2022-02-01 06:51:59 | 1641106319 | click | 0 | 17 |
| 2022-03-01 06:15:20 | 1641190520 | fetch | 2 | *null* |
| 2022-07-01 08:12:15 | 1641543135 | fetch | 2 | *null* |
| 2022-10-01 01:09:56 | 1641776996 | fetch | 2 | *null* |
| 2022-10-01 01:09:57 | 1641776997 | click | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-10-01 01:12:59 | 1641777179 | fetch | 2 | *null* |
| 22-10-01 01:13:01 | 1641777181 | click | 0 | *2* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cf63fc2ac88ead660cca751eda2b13b2)*

Comment: But how does it work.. What should Samy do next week when it needs debugging? Call you back to do their work for them again or maybe if you teach how it works they will be able to solve it themselves

Comment: The concept of your solution is valid, as long there is only one click per fetch, but (1) This question is tagged with [apache-spark-sql], not mysql (2) Take a look on your output dates (3) There is no need to CTE (4) `flag = 2` is not enough, it should also be `fetch`

Comment: Thanks @DavidדודוMarkovitz for such detail observations. 1. I don't have access to apache-spark-sql but I think this should work. 2. date format has been changed according to mysql. 3.CTE is removed and thanks again for pointing it out. 4. I have included fetch in the condition.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick:

```
select time, unix_time_seconds,event,flag,
case when event = 'click' then 
    unix_time_seconds - (select top 1 unix_time_seconds from table_event y where event = 'fetch' and flag = 2 AND y.unix_time_seconds <= z.unix_time_seconds order by y.unix_time_seconds desc) 
end as click_time  from table_event z order by unix_time_seconds
```

Comment: This question is tagged with [apache-spark-sql], not sql-server